# automate PDF presentation changes file to 72 dpi, I need it to remain at 300 dpi

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, file-size

I want to save individual PS6 files into one PDF to upload to kindle to create a book.
My images in PS6 are all 8"x6" @ 300dpi.  When I automate PDF presentation, no matter how I save it, the newly created PDF document becomes 72dpi.  If it keeps the 8" x 6" the file downsizes to 576 x432. (72dpi)
Even if I save without compression it will 
keep the 2400 x 1800 but changes the document to 33.34 x 25". (72dpi)
Please help!!  I need to keep the physical size to 8" x 6" but need the 300 dpi resolution

Comment: You should show what does and with what command and settings it does the actual "automated PDF presentation" Nobody can tell anything else than guesses if you keep the essentials secret.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to set the images resolution with the automate PDF presentation.

I suggest you create an action "Save as PDF" where you will be able to set the image quality :
Window > Actions (create an action and record your steps)

Then you can do a batch treatment with your action on all your psd files :
File > Automate > Batch (and select your feshly created action)

All your PSD files will be converted into PDF 300dpi files, then you will have to assemble them with Acrobat or another app.